# Count ocurrences inside a list from all the elements of another list

Tags: python, list

I have those two lists:

```
sub_list=['person1','person2']
global_list=['person1','person2','person3','person4','person5']
```

I want to know how many elements from sub_list are in global_list (2), is there a one liner?

Comment: Use `set`: `set(global_list).intersection(sub_list)`

Comment: ```len(set(sub_list) & set(global_list))```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `set`:

```
len(set(sub_list) & set(global_list))
```

Comment: Note that this will ignore non-unique elements in `sub_list`. If that is correct will depend on the use case.

Comment: @ScootCork Yes, this only applies if there are no duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Using `sum` and list comprehension

```
sum([e in global_list for e in sub_list])

>>> 2
```

Comment: Note that `sum` itself could accept generator so you can accomplish this by doing `sum(e in global_list for e in sub_list)`.